# Complex Analysis. Showing absolute convergence of principal part of Laurent series for a holomorphic function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am given that $f: D(P, r) \setminus \{ P \} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. I want to show that the principal part of the Laurent series expansion for $f$ converges absolutely on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{P\}$. Confused on how to proceed.

I know that the convergence is absolute on $D(P, r) \setminus \{ P \}$. I don't see how to extend the principal part to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{P\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principal part gets *better* as you get farther from the pole, since it has only negative powers of $(z - P)$. Apply a comparison test, using the fact that the series is convergent at some point $z \ne P$.

In particular, you can use the fact that

$$\left|\frac{a_n}{(z - P)^n}\right| \le \frac{|a_n|}{r^n}$$

for $z \notin \mathbb{D}(P, r)$.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out.

Comment: So basically take the limit of the right-hand side as $r \to \infty$?

Comment: No, because $r$ is just some fixed number.